# avg sql function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table employees

```
  EMPLOYEE_ID     FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME      HIRE_DATE    JOB_ID     SALARY  DEPARTMENT_ID
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    100             Steven        King         17-JUN-03    AD_PRES     24000     90
    101             Neena         Kochhar      21-SEP-05    AD_VP       17000     90
    102             Lex           De Haan      13-JAN-01    AD_VP       17000     90
    103             Alexander     Hunold       03-JAN-06    IT_PROG     9000      60
    104             Bruce         Ernst        21-MAY-07    IT_PROG     6000      60
    105             David         Austin       25-JUN-05    IT_PROG     4800      60
    106             Valli         Pataballa    05-FEB-06    IT_PROG     4800      60
    107             Diana         Lorentz      07-FEB-07    IT_PROG     4200      60
    109             Daniel        Faviet       16-AUG-02    FI_ACCOUNT  9000      100
    110             John          Chen         28-SEP-05    FI_ACCOUNT  8200      100
    111             Ismael        Sciarra      30-SEP-05    FI_ACCOUNT  7700      100
    112             Jose Manuel   Urman        07-MAR-06    FI_ACCOUNT  7800      100
    113             Luis          Popp         07-DEC-07    FI_ACCOUNT  6900      100
```

and table departments

```
DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME
-------------------------------
    30          Purchasing
    50          Shipping
    60          IT
    90          Executive
   100          Finance
```

I need to write 3 queries:

1. Get department name and number of employees in each department sorting ascending

   I tried this

   ```
   select count(e.employee_id), d.department_name 
   from t_employees e, t_departments d
   where d.department_id = e.department_id
   group by e.department_name
   order by count(e.employee_id);
   ```

   Not sure if it will work since I can not really try it.
2. Get department name and average salary where average salary by department is more or equal 5000

   Result table

   ```
    DEPARTMENT_NAME    AVERAGE_SALARY
    ---------------------------------
    Executive          19333,333
    IT                 5760
    Finance            7920`

   select d.department_name, AVG(e.salary) as AVARAGE_SALARY
   from t_departments d, t_employees e
   where d.department_id = e.department_id
     and avg(e.salary) >= '5000'
   group by d.department_name;
   ```
3. Get first name and last name of employees who have salary bigger than the average salary from the department they work in

   Result table

   ```
           FIRST_NAME          LAST_NAME
           ---------------------------------
           Steven              King
           Alexander           Hunold
           Bruce               Ernst
           Daniel              Faviet
           John                Chen
   ```

   I have no code for this one.

Comment: Three queries?  That seems like a lot.  And all in one question?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What do you mean by `Not sure if it will work since I can not really try it.`?  Your first query at least looks fine, other than the old join syntax.

Comment: Why can't you try your queries? You can use [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close.

I don't have your tables so I'll use Scott's sample schema. Try to apply it to your data model.

First:

```
SQL> select d.dname, count(*) cnt
  2  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  group by d.dname
  4  order by cnt desc;

DNAME                 CNT
-------------- ----------
SALES                   6
RESEARCH                5
ACCOUNTING              3
```

Second: not `where`, but `having`:

```
SQL> select d.dname, avg(e.sal) avg_sal
  2  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  group by d.dname
  4  having avg(e.sal) > 2000;           --> this

DNAME             AVG_SAL
-------------- ----------
ACCOUNTING     2916,66667
RESEARCH             2175

SQL>
```

Third:

```
SQL> with avgsal as
  2    (select deptno,
  3            round(avg(sal), 1) avgsal
  4     from emp
  5     group by deptno
  6    )
  7  select e.deptno, e.ename, e.sal, a.avgsal
  8  from emp e join avgsal a on a.deptno = e.deptno
  9  where e.sal > a.avgsal
 10  order by e.deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME             SAL     AVGSAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10 KING             5000     2916,7
        20 JONES            2975       2175
        20 SCOTT            3000       2175
        20 FORD             3000       2175
        30 ALLEN            1600     1566,7
        30 BLAKE            2850     1566,7

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```